# How to pass string parameter uing HMTL through<img src/> in a razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, blazor-webassembly

I have a quick question which is proving more difficult then I expected. I am using blazor webassembly on the visual studio .net 6.0 framework. On one of my razor pages I have a grid that was constructed through the components of a library called devexpress. My cell display template has a button to 'delete' records. I created a method to handle all edit/delete/add functions/actions but i need to pass a string through the parameter of a onclick event call.

When the button is clicked (in this case the button is a image) I need to pass a static string through. What would be the proper syntax. I've tried double quotes, single quotes, different tags nothing seems to work. Here is the tag and the syntax I have wrapped in it:

```
<img src="../images/icons/btnDeleteBG.png" class="custom-image-button" @onclick="() => HandlePanelActions(ClickEventRowDetail, //--string goes here--//)"/>
```

Comment: `nothing seems to work`: does it do nothing? does it do something other than what's expected? Is there an error? I'm not familiar with razor or blazor, but it seems that `HandlePanelActions(ClickEventRowDetail, '--string goes here--')` with single quotes should work.

Comment: single quotes doesnt work. it throws a exception. '' is considered a literal in this format. a single letter char is not ideal for this case.

Comment: What's your actual string? This doesn't seem like a JS error.

Comment: "Delete" is the string

Comment: any idea fellas? still banging my head on this

Comment: is it a literal string, or it comes from a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

> @code {
> private static string mystr = "strValue"; }
>
> <img src="../images/icons/btnDeleteBG.png" class="custom-image-button"
> @onclick="() => HandlePanelActions(ClickEventRowDetail ,mystr)" />

Comment: so just create a public instance. Is that good code though?

Comment: If this string is going to be constant even you could declare it as constant, and import from you application constants origin or static class, even is considered best practice to use an static const if it will have a constant value.